# Solo developer working on multiple projects and servers how to push to production/live server?

Tags: git

I have numerous projects on multiple servers (all in a large local network) and I am in the planning stage of introducing GIT as part of my workflow. I can setup an a central repository to put all my projects on and I understand the process of add commit etc from my local machine to the central respository.

I have two queries

1)How to I get the existing live projects onto the repository is that just a case of copying each project to the server and doing a git init?

2)After I've made a change on my local machine and submitted it to the central repository how do I push the changes to the live environment.

As it is only me working on the projects (at the moment) I'm looking for the least amount of steps

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> How to I get the existing live projects onto the repository is that just a case of copying each project to the server and doing a git init?

You can `git init` from anywhere the files are and then `commit` and `push` to the "central repository".

> After I've made a change on my local machine and submitted it to the central repository how do I push the changes to the live environment.

This is a bit too generic to give a precise answer but the idea would be to `pull` from the "live environment" (i.e. pulling the changes from the central repository into the live environment) rather than pushing to it.